# Equivalent of haskell's zipwith in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml

I have a list of 'a, and one 'b, and a function of type `'a -> 'b-> 'c`. I'm trying to apply the function to every element of the a-list with the b I already have and make a list of 'c. In haskell, I would do something like `zipWith(foobar) a-list (replicate (length a) b).` 
What's the equivalent way to do this in OCaml?

Comment: I think the problem description is confusing answers. You should say `list of 'a and one 'b`, if i understand correctly. In addition, if that's the case, then even in haskell, you don't need `zipWith`, a simple `map` can solve your problem.

Comment: Yikes. Please tell me you never actually wrote `zipWith f a (replicate (length a) b)`. Traversing `a` twice like that is very bad for streaming behavior. Much better to write `zipWith f a (repeat b)`.

Comment: It was back in undergrad when I was first learning Haskell, but yes yes I did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in your example you do not really need `zipWith`, you can use a simple `map`:

```
List.map (fun a -> f a b) a_list
```

This would be more efficient than a `List.map2` (the equivalent of `zipWith`) because OCaml doesn't handle lists the same way as Haskell so constructing a dummy list just for the sake of the iteration isn't really worth it.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding some context since I was confused at first by this answer -- I expected this to provide what the OP asked, instead of what the OP needed.

Answer (score 9):

"List.map2" is the equivalent of Haskell's "zipWith"

```
val map2 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list
```

Comment: the op has only one `b`, not `list of 'b`

Comment: This answers the question as phrased in the title, which is useful for future visitors.

Comment: @MartinJambon hmm I agree

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in OCaml would be:

```
 open Core_kernel.Std

 let replicate n b = List.init n ~f:(fun _ -> b)
 List.(map2_exn a (replicate (length b) b) ~f:your_function)
```

This code arises few questions, however. Like, are you sure, that you want to have a list as a second argument of your function? And, what is the reason, to duplicate the second argument, instead of passing it as a free variable to your function, as @PatJ has suggested. And it is not all about lazy vs. eager evaluation. In Haskell you still need to traverse the list, and `b` will be traversed twice. The fact that computation is lazy, doesn't mean that it will be any faster, when it is evaluated.

But still, OCaml's Core library provides a lazy list named `Sequence`, that has behavior similar to the Haskell's one. The code would be the same, modulo the module name, i.e., just substitute `List` with a `Sequence`.

Comment: Well, I don't know much of Haskell's behavior and assumed it was optimized without checking. (lazy me :-p)